# Compute possible values of gradient vector with length of gradient and level curve?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

How would I compute the possible values of a gradient vector, without knowing $f(x,y)$? I have the level curve $y = 9x+6$ and $|\nabla f(3,14)|$ = 10.

I think I should take the perpendicular slope of the level curve, giving me $\left<-1, 9\right>$. So this would give me the direction. I also have the length of the gradient, 10. I'm not entirely sure how to tie the two together to get the gradient vector.

Comment: Are you finding gradient at $(3,14)$? Your approach is correct but the direction vector you have written is incorrect.

Comment: I have to find the possible values for the gradient at point(3,14) using the length of the gradient and creating a vector from the level curve, why is the direction of the vector incorrect?

Comment: First of all, are you sure you have the correct level curve? I find this hard to believe seeing as $(3, 14) \not\in \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y = 9x + 6\}.$ Also, how would you compute the normal to a general level surface given by $F(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = c,$ where $F$ is differentiable and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant?